How to solve this symmetric determinant?
seeing this as symmetric, I've tried solving characteristic value but no gain so far.
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & ... & n \\ 
2 & 3 & 4 & ... & 1 \\ 
3 & 4 & 5 & ... & 2 \\ 
...\\
n & 1 & 2 & ... & n-1\\
\end{vmatrix}

See determinant of anti-circulant matrix for a generalization.
